# Gradle Dependency Conflict: "the unnamed module reads package from both" Errors

Tags: firebase, gradle, dependency-management

I'm encountering a series of dependency-related errors after adding implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0' to my Gradle project. These errors seem to be related to conflicts between packages from different libraries, including io.grpc, javax.annotation, and com.google.longrunning. The errors are of the form:

```
error: the unnamed module reads package javax.annotation from both java.annotation and jsr305
error: the unnamed module reads package io.grpc from both grpc.api and grpc.context
error: the unnamed module reads package com.google.longrunning from both proto.google.common.protos and gax.grpc
```

I've tried several approaches to resolve these conflicts, including excluding packages and updating dependencies, but I haven't been successful so far.

Here's a summary of my project setup:

- I'm using Gradle as my build system.
- I added the Firebase Admin SDK as a dependency in my build.gradle file.
- Other dependencies in my project might be contributing to these conflicts.
- I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve these dependency conflicts and get my project to build successfully. Are there specific configurations or exclusions I should add to my build.gradle file? Or is there a recommended way to handle these conflicts when using the Firebase Admin SDK alongside other dependencies?

Any help or insights on how to address these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Firebase Admin SDK version: 6.11.0